# How can I get token and login values from string via regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string:

```
"Token token="ZuS6HNdwXsCDo2Moq2nx", login="login.login""
```

I want to get `ZuS6HNdwXsCDo2Moq2nx` and `login.login`.

How can I get token and login values using regexp?

I use `/"\w+"/` to get token value, but I can't get login value. Maybe the is another alternative to this?

Comment: You can use Rubular.com to test out your Ruby Regexes! Love that Tool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ts = 'Token token="ZuS6HNdwXsCDo2Moq2nx", login="login.login"'
ts.scan(/(\w+)="([^"]*)"/).to_h
#⇒ {
#  "login" => "login.login",
#  "token" => "ZuS6HNdwXsCDo2Moq2nx"
#}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
str='Token token="ZuS6HNdwXsCDo2Moq2nx", login="login.login"'

r = /
    (?<=\stoken=) # match string in positive look behind
    \"[a-z0-9]+\" # match > 0 letters or numbers between double quotes
    /ix           # case insensitive and extended mode      
str[r]
  #=> "\"ZuS6HNdwXsCDo2Moq2nx\""

str[/(?<=\slogin=)\"[a-z0-9.]+\"/i]
  #=> "\"login.login\""
```

Comment: The only thing we know about token and login values, is they are delimited by double quotes, that’s why `"[^"]*"` is likely safer for match.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I assumed the token and login had to be preceded by `" token="` and `" login="` for four reasons: the OP referred to them as "token"  and "login" values, the `=` signs, the possible difficulty in determining which is which and the possibility that the string contains unrelated quoted substrings. But it doesn't matter, as the OP now has answers for alternative interpretations.

Comment: Positive lookbehinds are great. I told about _values matching_.

Answer (score 0):

Because `login` contains (or can contain?) other characters than what is included in `\w`, you can use a custom character class: `[\w.]+`

Please note that the dot inside a character class matches itself, not *any* character.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
/token=\"\w+\"/.match(your_string)
```

but this would return `token="ZuS6HNdwXsCDo2Moq2nx"`, but you can easily take the token out by `.split('"')[1]` for example.

This way makes sure the value you have returned is preceded by `token=` and surrounded by double quotes.